# Open a non-diff window in vimdiff

Tags: vim, vimdiff

Sometimes I'm using vimdiff and want to grab code and drop it in a 3rd window/buffer for later reference. When that window is open, though, just about everything is identified as a diff (because it's purposely different than the other two files).  How can I open a window in non-diff mode while using vimdiff?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prevent a window from being diffed with the others by doing `:diffoff` in that window.

See also `:h :diffoff`.